# Entity Framework 5 performing full table scan

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following code:

```
public List<anEntity> Get(int page, int pagesize, Func<anEntity, IComparable> orderby)
{            
    using (var ctx = new MyContext())
    {                
        return ctx.anEntity.OrderBy(orderby).Skip(pagesize * page).Take(pagesize).ToList();                    
    }           
}
```

When I check my database profile (SqlServer 2012) I can see an horrible full table scan without any "TOP" clause.

The interesting part:

If I do something similar but specifying a concrete orderby:

```
return ctx.anEntity.OrderBy(x => x.aField).Skip(pagesize * page).Take(pagesize).ToList();
```

The profile shows a beautiful "TOP" clause.

I would like to avoid having lot's of methods, one for each "orderby" possibility. Any hint would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the "order by" field is the same in both cases?

Comment: I think your `orderby` parameter should be `Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because your `orderby` parameter is a function rather than expression. There is no way to translate an arbitrary function into SQL, so all your data has to be on the client side before that function is called.

Change the parameter type to `Expression<Func<anEntity, T>>`, where `T` is a new generic parameter that you should add to your `Get` method, and it will work as expected.

Of course, you won't be able to use a custom `IComparable`, but there is no way around that: custom code cannot be translated into SQL.

Comment: Ok, the Expression<Func<anEntity, bool>> worked like a champ for the "Where" clausule. Doing return ctx.anEntity.Where(predicate).OrderBy( x => x.aField ).Skip(pagesize * page).Take(pagesize).ToList(); Where predicate is the expression. Any chance to do the same with the orderby? thanks a ton

Comment: I tryed with Expression<Func<anEntity, IComparable>> and works. Thanks for the hinds. Now looks like return ctx.anEntity.Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderby).Skip(pagesize * page).Take(pagesize).ToList(); I really love when I can do it DRY without hurting the db!

Comment: @Jordi: Ah, right, sorry, confused it with the `Where` method. `OrderBy`'s parameter cannot be just `bool`, it should be polymorphic in return type. I have corrected the answer, take a look.

Comment: @Jordi: you don't have to restrict yourself to `IComparable`, make it a generic type.

Comment: Thanks. I just learned a lot today. I am new with EF and I wanna make things right.

Comment: @Jordi: It's not just EF. This kind of things are [relatively] new functional-style features of C#, which were pushed into it from Haskell. If you like to learn, check out this: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals/Lecture-Series-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals-Chapter-1